# Perl logfile pattern matching loop inside loop

Tags: perl

I have logfile which is structured like this (repetitively):

`<header>
<timestamp>2018-05-18T13:22:35.842</timestamp>
<requestedService>requestSchufameldungAbgeben</requestedService>
 ...
<errorCode>/IWBEP/CX_MGW_BUSI_EXCEPTION</errorCode>`

What I want is to go down until the errorstring "CX_MGW_BUSI_EXCEPTION" was found then and then extract the errorstring and the timestamp above. Any idea on how I can do this?
The script should loop over the whole file doing this repetitively.

I have tried something like this but I don't know how to proceed further:

```
while(my $line=<F>) {
    if ( $line=~/^\s*<timestamp>/) {
                    while(my $nextline =<F>) {
                            if ($nextline =~ /BUSI_EXCEPTION/) {
                            print;
                            flag = 1;
                            }
                    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an XML document? If so, you should probably use an XML parser. But it's hard to be sure without seeing more of the input.

Comment: No it is not an xml-file. The logfile itself just has an xml-like structure

Comment: Can you please add at least two complete sections of the input file to your question, along with the output you would expect for those inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Just save any timestamp and print it when needed:

```
while (my $line = <F>)
{
    $timestamp = $1 if $line =~ /^\s*<timestamp>(.*)</;
    print $timestamp, "\t", $1, "\n" if $line =~ />(.*BUSI_EXCEPTION.*)</
}
```